# Is the IBM AppScan XSS vulnerability on Google Analytics about the "cross-domain tracking query string parameter" a false positive?

Tags: xss, google

The IBM AppScan reports an XSS vulnerability on Google Analytics regarding the cross-domain tracking query string parameter. I'm trying to address this issue, but:

1. I haven't been able to reproduce it, even in non-CSP supporting browsers (specifically IE 9), and,
2. I wouldn't know how to fix it if I could reproduce it, given that it's not in any code that I control.

Has anyone else seen this issue reported? Can I safely assume that it's a false positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an XSS vulnerability reported on google-analytics, more information can be found on the following pages:

- http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2014-9174/
- http://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/xss-vulnerability-injected-google-analytics-executed-ioss-gmail-application/

Make sure to update your version, when your version of google-analytics is the same to this one reported.